# Changing CSS values with checkbox and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I am trying to hide and display a div based on the state of a checkbox using javascript but I don't seem to be getting it right. I am not very experienced with js so I could be missing something very obvious. Any advice would be much appreciated. the target div is the on-toggle div in the second half of the html code.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=toggle]");

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("on-toggle").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("on-toggle").style.height = "auto";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("on-toggle").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("on-toggle").style.height = "0";
    }
```

```html
<div id="switch">
                <h2 id="CTA-switch">Turn creativity on </h2>
                <div class="switch">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="toggle">
                 <label for="toggle">
                    <i class="bulb">
                      <span class="bulb-center"></span>
                      <span class="filament-1"></span>
                      <span class="filament-2"></span>
                      <span class="reflections">
                        <span></span>
                      </span>
                      <span class="sparks">
                        <i class="spark1"></i>
                        <i class="spark2"></i>
                        <i class="spark3"></i>
                        <i class="spark4"></i>
                      </span>
                    </i>    
                  </label>
                </div>
            </div>

<div id="on-toggle"> 
    <div id="references">
        
        <h1>REFERENCE SITES</h1>
        

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to toggle? Your script indicates it will have id `on-toggle`, but your html has no element of this, or indeed any similar, id.

Comment: Yes sorry, the element does exist in my code. It contains a grid of buttons and images. I forgot to add the snippet in

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to grab an actual element so your javascript code works. The id "on-toggle" does not currently exist on any element on your html code.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I forgot to add that snippet in. The ID does exist and contains a grid of buttons and images.